# Creating a responsive grid, stacks, with responsive images

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I created a question earlier about making a responsive grid, and got it working thanks to the help of everyone here, but now I'm struggling with the next stage.

I want a grid with three columns (three images) with are each 33.3% in width. I then have an image inside the `max-width:100%` in order to make them scale to the width of their containers.

Now I'm stuck on making them stack at an average mobile resolution. So essentially when they become too small to be easily viewed as three in a row, I want them to go down to 2 on a row (making 3 rows totalling 6 images) and then down to just one per row in a long stack.

JS Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abrdn/15/)

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need to learn [how to use media queries](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries) and [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) before proceeding further.

In your specific case, you can do something like [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/cJB8C/) (narrow the window to see it in action):

```
.product{
    width:50%; /* initially, each row contains 2 products */
    float: left;
    /* no need for display:block; */
}

@media screen and (min-width:450px) { /* <--- this is a media query */

    /*
        everything inside this media query will be processed
        only if the viewport is larger then 450px
    */

    .product{
        width:33.3%; /* larger screens will diplay 3 products per row */
        /* float is already declared */
    }

}
```

Obviously, this is just an example. You know what will be inside each `.product` element. Just master media queries and you'll be able to do any variation.

For instance, if you want only one product per line on small screens, you can do something like:

```
.product{
    /* nothing here! 1 product per row */
}

@media only screen and (min-width:450px) and (max-width:1023px) {
    .product{
        width:50%; /* 2 products per row */
        float:left;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
    .product{
        width:33.3%; /* 3 products per row */
        float:left;
    }
}
```

...and so on. This can be done in many different ways, it just depends on your project.

Comment: you will still need a min-width, because otherwise they won't drop further to 1 column. +1 for the media query though, didn't remember that.

Comment: Thanks @Asad, btw `product` is a div, which default display is `block`, so from 0 to 450px they'll occupy a full "row"

Comment: No probs. From 0 to 450, they will still have width 50%, because you explicitly set them that way and they're floating. You can continue to define this for each range, but I think the best approach is to simply define what you think the minimum look-good width for your image is (and optionally, what the maximum look-good width is)

Answer (score 0):

Is something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abrdn/18/) what you're looking for? The trick here is to put an absolute minimum width on the product divs, which combined with the float property gives you your desired result.

```
#content{
  width:90%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-right:5%;
}

.product{
    width:33.3%;
    min-width:100px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
}

.product img{
max-width:100%;
}

body{
    background-color:#666;
}
```

Comment: Could you please leave a comment explaining the downvote so I can improve the answer? Thanks!